How can one reasonably dismiss hypotheses without Occam’s razor?
Suppose the sun is shining and you see the sun in the sky.
You have two hypotheses:
A) The sun exists in the external world and is shining in the sky. That’s why you see it.
B) You are in a simulation where the sun being in the sky is merely being simulated to you
If you decide not to adopt Occam’s razor, what reason would you have to believe A) over B)?
One may argue that there is a lack of evidence/explanatory power for B) not available in A) but since the end result (an appearance of the sun in the sky) is expected on both theories, I’m not sure how this follows.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Occam's Razor is just a helpful tool because in the continuous-improvement nature of science, starting with overly-simple theories  and building up is easier than starting with overly-complex theories and tearing down.  We don't actually need it to pick between theories, because we can rely 100% on predictive power.
Turning our attention to your hypothesis:
B) The universe is a simulation, but the simulation aligns with physics and cannot be detected in any way.
From a science perspective, theories are predictive tools.  In other words, a theory IS its predictions, and the concomitant vernacular "explanations" are only there to help with human intuition. Physicists would therefore not bother arguing B) vs A), as B) is functionally equivalent to A).  Since it predicts the same outcomes as A), it IS A), and the words "...but it's a simulation" don't actually add anything to the theory, because they don't change the predictions of the theory.

Both of the hypotheses I just conjured up predict the same outcome and predict the same experience of seeing the sun. So, again, how would you reason picking A) over B) without Occam’s razor? “I don’t care about it” isn’t really a valid answer in my opinion

There may be some detectable consequences to it being a simulation, though. For instance, if it's a simulation then there's a possibility that if we look close enough we can see floating-point rounding errors. So you still need a way to decide between two theories that both match the as-yet-known evidence, while making different predictions about future evidence.

As I have said in my hidden answer, in practice we decide between competing theories - say Newtonian gravitation v General Relativity- principally on how well they accord with the rest of what we take to be our observed reality, the extent to which they are consistent with the rest of our collective intellectual model of the world…

@Syed, IMHO, there are no valid tools to distinguish between them, and Occam's Razor is also not a valid tool to distinguish between them.  It's not a question of "caring" so much a question of theoretical limitations on epistemology.

@Him why isn’t it a valid tool? Intuitively, the more complex something is, the more components, and the lower the probability of all of them to align

@Syed I think you're making an empirical observation, or maybe taking a limit.  Check out, e.g. Poisson distribution.

Prediction is everything. The brain predicts and then feeds back the error output. That's it. You understand everything now.

@syed: simplicity may justify a preference. It does not justify a conclusion. The problem with the simulation hypothesis is that, short of a flaw in the simulation, it is untestable. I too find it a needless complication, and prefer to ignore it as such, but I know that in the way science knows most things, that is, non-simulation  strikes me as the best model I currently have available. Others may be more certain, or less certain, and that's fine; until a consensus is reached, philosophy may be useful for exploring the implications of one answer or the other. If there are any.

If you are still looking for a convincing argument for accepting or rejecting God(s)  beyond "this is what makes sense to me",  I believe we have spent millennia proving that faith regarding the unobservable (including both belief and disbelief) simply has to be taken on faith,


You have two hypotheses:
A) The sun exists in the external world and is shining in the sky. That’s why you see it.
B) You are in a simulation where the sun being in the sky is merely being simulated to you
If you decide not to adopt Occam’s razor, what reason would you have to believe A) over B)?

A hypothesis is a statement based on the best available information. It is NOT a conclusion.
Which hypothesis matches the best current available information? Clearly, the answer is A. Does the available information prove definitively that B is not true? If you believe the answer is no, then research and experimentation must be performed to fill in the missing gaps in your current information to reach a conclusion.

Occam's razor is not a reason to dismiss anything.
It may be a reason to set that aside and put your emphasis on testing the one that is easier to work with, and to test, first, purely because we do not have infinite resources and it would be nice if the universe was simple.
If the simpler theory fails under testing, which includes simply not being able to resolve the questions you want to ask, it is reasonable to examine a more complicated answer and see if it works better. And that is how you dismiss a theory without resorting to the razor: you show that it's broken (at least outside a specific domain), and seek a theory that works in both domains.
Or, if you simply have a hunch that the more complicated is correct, you are welcome to continue to explore the more complicated one. Don't expect people to follow you there unless it correctly answers something the prettier one doesn't.
The razor is a tool for directing research effort and selecting which model to use in the absence of complete knowledge. It will not always be the right tool, and that's fine.
(Typos. Grr. Sorry.)

If a theory “fails” then it is not part of consideration under Occam’s razor in the first place. The razor says to not worry about hypotheses that add more entities but still explain the data at hand. Still explaining data requires not failing to explain it

It is under consideration until it fails. At that point the razor is no longer part of the discussion, though it may still be helpful in deciding which failed theory to try to repair or bound. Tool for task . Screwdrivers make bad hammers, but hammers make worse screwdrivers.

I do this every day while programming. But thank God for .Net Framework, which makes a lot of things simple, and correct. Spent 2 days recently finding out that I really did need to create an empty, never used default constructor. (Oops, wrong SE. blush)
